# Bison parser: When do I need 'return' and when I don't?

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

right now I'm writing my first work in Bison parser, a calculator.

I have noticed that for rules like:

```
expr_double: expr_double '+' expr_double          { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr_double '-' expr_double           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        .
        .
        .
        etc...
```

I do not need to specify the end of parsing with 'return 0', and the parser knows when to stop and finish the job.
This works for inputs such as print double_expr: 5, 10+10, etc...

But, for the following rule, I need to write 'return 0' in the end, or else it wouldn't work:

```
print_expr: PRINT expr_int      { cout<<$2<<endl; return 0; }
        | PRINT expr_double     { printf("%.3f\n", $2); return 0; }
        .
        .
        .
        etc...
```

I did not supply any further of my code since I don't think its relevant. If needed, I would post more of the code, but I think the difference is shown here.

Any ideas why I need 'return' in the later rule, but no need in the first one?

EDIT:
Added the first and second rules of my program...

```
program: command '\n'
        ;

command: print_expr
        | define_var
        | assign_var
        ;
```

Comment: Careful of tagging... Flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer; and Flex is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: "It doesn:t work" is about zero bits of information. Post error messages and any other unexpected output.

Answer (score 4):

In normal use of bison, you don't return at all. Instead, the "start" rule reduces and then `yyparse()` returns normally.

I doubt that you want `return` in any of your actions.

That said, I have seen the use of return used this way. It just causes `yyparse()` to return prematurely. The 'start' rule hasn't been reduced so at this point your input has not matched the whole grammar.

Think of that returning rule as short circuiting your grammar. ***Once the rule with the return in the action reduces, `yyparse()` will return right away and will stop parsing at that point.*** Probably **NOT** what you want.

In other words, as soon as your parser sees a print statement it will stop parsing.

---

Update: Probably what you want is to parse a number of commands, one after another. The grammar for that would look something like this:

```
program: commands '\n'
        ;
commands : command
         | commands command
         ;
command: print_expr
        | define_var
        | assign_var
        ;
```

Comment: I've added the first two rules, can you see a problem?

Comment: Your parser will parse one of three things: a print statement, an assign statement or a define statement. It will not parse a combination of those. It will only parse one. See the edit of the answer to show how to parse more than one command if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is your lexer return a newline character as itself ? Eg when lex sees a '\n', do you return '\n'? If not, that would prevent your grammar from matching and result in the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Yes my lexer does return *yytext when it sees '\n'.. and the commands rule did not solve the problem :/ I added it and removed the 'return' and getting an error after doing more than one command.

Comment: For further help, you would need to post your bison file, your lex file and your input file. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Its ok, as long as it works I'll leave it as is for now. Got another question tho, regarding how to add variables to my calculator. Do I need to open a new thread or can I somehow ask you personally?

Comment: Ask another question, but post more code this time. It's hard to answer when we aren't given much to go on.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to `return` directly from the parser, you might leak, as you will skip all the code that cleans up the stack.  If you want to quit with success, use `YYACCEPT`, otherwise `YYABORT`.